# Applying to job when transcript is bad

Tags: applications

I am applying to a job asking for transcript.  Mines is not good (2.8gpa and also took 6yrs to finish Bachelors due to not taking my classes seriously for select semesters).  Should I just forget about applying for this job and not ruin my reputation when they see my transcript or try anyways.

Comment: What reputation do you have to ruin?

Comment: `You miss 100% of the shots you don't take.` - Wayne Gretzky

Comment: I doubt anyone really cares about grades as long as you graduated.

Comment: I made a 2.73 in college but now I work for a huge tech company and I’m doing extremely well at my job. During my interview I gave it everything I could to demonstrate my skills and experience. It is not impossible to get the job you want. It is impossible, however, if you don’t try. Your reputation that you worry about is nonexistent, especially straight out of college.

Answer (score 5):

If you are applying to companies for your first professional job after completing a bachelor's degree, then pretty much every one of them is going to ask for your transcript. There's really no getting around it, unless you want to remove it from your resume, but then you will have to explain what you did for all that time. What you need to do is to minimise it's impact on their impression of you.

Did you improve towards the end of the degree? Then you can say that as you matured, you realised that you needed to take work and study more seriously. This is best placed in a cover letter.

Are there subjects where you graded better than your average? Then focus on jobs where those subjects are desirable. Highlight these as part of your resume/CV.

Make the degree less relevant. Take additional courses and get additional certification.

The good news is that once you get that first job, and as long as you are professional and keep improving your skills, your degree will be less relevant when you look to move to your next job. And then even more so.

As a side note, different schools calculate GPA differently - I know some that calculate it out of 4, others out of 5, and yet more out of 10. So it's hard to say how bad 2.8 is (2.8 out of 4 doesn't sound all that terrible to me - my final degree score was 46% but I highlighted those subjects where I performed well and got my first engineering job - after applying to somewhere close to a hundred companies and getting through to a couple of interviews).

Answer (score 3):

**Some companies don't actually check the transcript**

I have a couple friends who work or have worked in human resources. Across 6 large companies (I admit this is anecdotal) all said they asked for transcripts, but only half actually ordered them and only one meaningfully cared what it really said rather than just stuffing it into the file. They say a lot of things in the job posting to discourage certain types of applicants, but aren't willing to put the money and time into enforcing those things.

Now, the number of companies that check transcripts is going to be higher than 1/6 as my friends are from the more casual industries like oil and gas, tech, and large hospitality companies and not banking or consulting. But the point is that what the job posting says may not be true or may only be procedurally true.

**Don't disqualify yourself from the start.**

Comment: Strong +1 to the last sentence. Always let the company decide if you're qualified for the job or not, don't do that for them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're fresh out of school, a lot of jobs will ask for transcripts. If they reject you, then they reject you, no harm in trying.